# How can I prevent OutOfMemoryError when creating a JSONArray from an SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android

How do I solve the OutOfMemoryError when making a pretty large JsonArray from a sqlite database?
If the data size is small, it works pretty well, but when the data size reaches over 80–100 MB, I get this OutOfMemoryError. How do I solve that?

```
public JSONArray makeJsonArrayFromDB() {


        String myPath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        JSONArray jsonArray;

        try (SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)) {

            Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + MY_TABLE, null);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectNotes = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                        try {
                            if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                                jsonObjectNotes.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),   
cursor.getString(i));
                            } else {
                                jsonObjectNotes.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                jsonArray.put(jsonObjectNotes);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

What could I do to make it work with large data sets?

Comment: Use Thread or Coroutines. Or better yet, use background processes.

Answer (score 1):

So it is really big size. I think the best solution is return `Cursor` or some abstract object that can be iterated. It can help with OOM.

You can also use the paging. You can use a **[LIMIT ... OFFSET ...](https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt)** clause in your query.

```
public JSONArray makeJsonArrayFromDB(int limit, int offset) {

    String myPath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

    try (SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)) {

        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + MY_TABLE + "LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset, null);
    ...
```

How to use:
`makeJsonArrayFromDB(20, 0)` ... `makeJsonArrayFromDB(20, 20)` ... `makeJsonArrayFromDB(20, 40)`

Comment: I tried worked pretty well. The number of rows changes, so in that case how to determine the size of limit and offset?

Comment: The *LIMIT* clause to select a limited number of records.
The *OFFSET* clause specifies the number of rows to skip before starting to return rows from the query.
Assume you should read 20 items at once.
Your limit is 20. So, the first page will be `LIMIT = 20` and `OFFSET = 0 or 0 * LIMIT, the second page will be `LIMIT = 20` and `OFFSET = 20 or  = 1 * LIMIT), the third page will be `LIMIT = 20` and `OFFSET = 40 or 2 * LIMIT`.